# How to prevent multiple ajax calls on play button clicked in audio element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send ajax request to update the value in the database , once the play button is called it sends data to process page for updating the database. But the issue is once the play button is clicked `AJAX` fires up multiple times. I have tried restricting it using a flag but didn't work.

```
var requestSent = false;
var current_audio = document.getElementById("current_audio");
current_audio.addEventListener("play", function() {
   var data;
   var d = $('#update_counter').text();
   if (d == null)
      data = d;
   else
      data = 0;
   var date = $('#current_dat').text();
   if (!requestSent) {
      requestSent = true;
      $.ajax({
         url: "process.php",
         type: "POST",
         data: {
            data: data,
            date: date
         },
         async: false,
         cache: false,
         success: function(dataResult) {
            var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
            if (dataResult.statusCode == 200) {
               $("#update_counter").val(dataResult);
            } else if (dataResult.statusCode == 201) {
               alert("Error occured !");
            }
         },
         complete: function() {
            requestSent = false;
         },
      });
   }
});
```

As per the request from the comments I am also adding the HTML that is rendered

```
<tr class="hidden" style="background-color:'.$result3["planet_color"].';border:1px solid black;padding:10px;color:white;">
<td start="'.strtotime($time_prev).'" finish="'.strtotime($time_next).'" style="padding:20px;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                                <p>
                                    <audio class="play_audio" controls loop>
                                       <source src="'.$result3["planet_mantra"].'" type="audio/mpeg">
                                       Your browser does not support the audio tag.
                                    </audio>
                                </p>
                                <p>Times Played :   
                                    <span id="current_dat" style="display:none;">'.$current_date.'</span> 
                                    <span id="update_counter"></span>
                                </p>
                                <p style="font-size:10px;">Location : <strong>'.$place.'</strong></p>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    </td>

            </tr>
```

Now since the only one  is visible at a time out of 24 elements , i want to access the play button of that  only

Comment: Probably addEventListener is called multiple times. Can’t see your full code so not sure. Try to  refactor the handler from anonymous function to named function e.g. "handler" - current_audio.addEventListener("play", handler) and in complete parameter do current_audio.removeEventListener("play", handler)

Comment: May i know what part of the code you want to see ... This is the full code being used to send the ajax request

Comment: The html and if there's more JavaScript in the same file. Might be helpful

Comment: I have added , please check

Comment: Where is the element with id `current_audio`? can't see it in your html

Comment: elem.parent().removeClass('hidden');
       elem.find('audio').attr('autoplay','autoplay');
       elem.find('audio').attr('id','current_audio');
          //console.log(start+'-'+datetimestamp+'-'+finish);
          var requestSent = false;
          var current_audio = document.getElementById("current_audio");
      current_audio.addEventListener("play", function () 
       {

Comment: I created a simple version of your code to make it easier to debug and it works fine. So far I can't say why your code causes it to fire the code inside the play listener multiple times.
What if you replace the code in the listener to something very simple like `console.log()` and see if it's called multiple times?